# Is there a bug in the C++ random generator?

Tags: c++, random

I've written a small program at https://github.com/lub094/Roulette. It simulates a roulette and calculates the times a sequence of same color sectors with length n, has been reached. So if you spin it 4 times and you get RED, BLACK, BLACK, BLACK that will give you 2 sequences with lengths 1, and 1 sequence of lengths 2 and 3.

The problem comes when I spin it more than a million times. Then the longest sequence reached is absolutely always 15. I've tried it with 500 000 000 000 spins and yet again, the longest sequence is 15. I've done the math, I've tried it on java and this seems to be an abnormal behavior. I've tried putting the seed srand() in the main, in the constructor of the Roulette class and in the method calling rand(), but there seems to be no difference.

This is how I'm currently seeding the rand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Roulette.cpp"

int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));

    Roulette roulette;
    roulette.spin(10000000);

    return 0;
}
```

In the class Roulette, I have the method getRandomColor() where I call the rand() method:

```
SectorColor getRandomColor() {
    long long randomNumber = rand();

    if (randomNumber % 2 == 0) {
        return SectorColor::RED;
    } else {
        return SectorColor::BLACK;
    }
}
```

I'm running it on windows on MinGW's latest version as for this date. The IDE I'm using is Eclipse.

I can't find any place where there could be a mistake, so thanks in advance if you try to investigate :)

Comment: rand() is, to put it shortly, broken. Use C++'s random number generator engines. There's an example in this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: Include your platform with your question, please. MSVC for example, has a historically dreadful `RAND_MAX` of `0x7FFF`, (i.e. 2^15-1). If you're going to use C++ prngs, use [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), its whats for dinner.

Comment: You also need to show the relevant portions of your code, including how you seed the generator. Its not acceptable to tell people to go offsite and fetch your code. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Err, it may have dreadful range, but that's because it intentionally throws away the lower bits which have dreadful randomness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
    if (randomNumber % 2 == 0) {
        return SectorColor::RED;
    } else {
        return SectorColor::BLACK;
    }
```

It's well known that many implementations of `rand()` have [very poor randomness in the lower bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Advantages_and_disadvantages_of_LCGs).  Try something like:

```
return (randomNumber & 1024)? SectorColor::BLACK : SectorColor::RED;
```

which uses bit 10 instead of bit 0.

Moving to the C++ template-based PRNGs, such as Mersenne Twister, would be even better.

Side note, naming include files with a .cpp extension is very bad style.

Comment: Making that change fixed it. I'll research further why such problem exists, thanks!
About the include, it was mostly because I wrote the code java style, yet, isn't it normal to include files with .cpp extensions, at least when the file uses templates?

Comment: @lub094: It's normal to use an extension such as `.h` or `.hpp` or `.templ` for files which will be included.  And I added a link to wikipedia where the lack of randomness is explained.

Comment: Given the 500 billion spins and a `rand()` period commonly 2^32 (i.e. ~4 billion), you're getting ~116.41 runs through the same sequence - with the same longest repeating sequence length; seems to me changing which bit you inspect may well change that sequence length from the 15 observed for bit 0, but it will still be same every time the program runs.  Only the suggestion to abandon `rand` - presumably for [C++11 random number generators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) - promises more variability.

Comment: @Tony: I'm fairly sure the 500 billion trials were performed to test whether the distribution differed significantly from a negative binomial, not that so many are needed in practice.